# Why do I need to send a message twice to trigger Indy's OnExecute event?

Tags: tcp, c++builder, indy

I am working on an application that works as a "man in the middle" to analyze a protocol (ISO 8583) sent over TCP/IP.

The main idea is to get the raw binary data and convert it to a string for parsing and decoding the protocol.

For this, I am using the `TIdMappedPortTCP` component.

I am testing with [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility).

I am working with:

Windows 11 Home

Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.4 Version 27.0.40680.4203

Delphi and C++ Builder 10.4 Update 2

Indy 10.6.2.0

More context can be found in these questions:

[Where can I find a fully working example of a TCP Client and Server for Indy in C++Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432658/)

[Parsing bytes as BCD with Indy C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74462592/)

**The problem is that I have to send the message twice to trigger the `OnExecute` event**. I think this might be length related but I haven't found the issue. Other than that the program does what is expected from it.

If I use this data in Hercules:

```
00 04 60 02
```

equivalent to:

```cpp
"\x00\x04\x60\x02"
```

[image]

My program processes everything correctly:

[image]

Here is the code:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::MITMProxyExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    static int index;
    TIdBytes ucBuffer;
    UnicodeString usTemp1;
    UnicodeString usTemp2;
    int calculated_length;

    // getting the length in Hexa
    calculated_length = ReadMessageLength(AContext);
    // reads data
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes(ucBuffer, calculated_length);

    // displays string with calculated length and size of the data
    usTemp2 = UnicodeString("calculated length = ");
    usTemp2 += IntToStr(calculated_length);
    usTemp2 += " ucBuffer.Length = ";
    usTemp2 += IntToStr(ucBuffer.Length);
    Display->Lines->Add(usTemp2);
    // converts the binary data into a a Hex String for visualization
    usTemp1 = BytesToHexString(ucBuffer);

    // adds an index to distinguish from previous entries.
    usTemp2 = IntToStr(index);
    usTemp2 += UnicodeString(": ");
    usTemp2 += usTemp1;
    Display->Lines->Add(usTemp2);
    index++;
}
```

Here is the code for the functions called there. By the way, is there a better way to convert the bytes to a hex string?

```cpp
// Convert an array of bytes to a hexadecimal string
UnicodeString BytesToHexString(const TBytes& bytes)
{
    // Create an empty UnicodeString to store the hexadecimal representation of the bytes
    UnicodeString hexString;

    // Iterate through each byte in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        // Convert the byte to a hexadecimal string and append it to the result string
        hexString += IntToHex(bytes[i], 2);
    }

    // Return the hexadecimal string
    return hexString;
}

// Read the first two bytes of an incoming message and interpret them as the length of the message
int ReadMessageLength(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    int calculated_length;

    // Use the 'ReadSmallInt' method to read the length of the message from the first two bytes
    calculated_length = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadSmallInt();
    // converting from hex binary to hex string
    UnicodeString bcdLength = UnicodeString().sprintf(L"%04x", calculated_length);
    // converting from hex string to int
    calculated_length = bcdLength.ToInt();
    // decrease length
    calculated_length -= 2;
    return calculated_length;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have created a class to update the TEditRich control. But the problem persist, I need to send the message twice to be processed and the application freezes when trying to close it. This is my class:

```cpp
class TAddTextToDisplay : public TIdSync {
private:
    UnicodeString textToAdd;

public:
    __fastcall TAddTextToDisplay(UnicodeString str) {
        // Store the input parameters in member variables.
        textToAdd = str;
    }

    virtual void __fastcall DoSynchronize() {
        if (textToAdd != NULL) {
            // Use the input parameters here...
            Form1->Display->Lines->Add(textToAdd);
        }
    }

    void __fastcall setTextToAdd(UnicodeString str) {
        textToAdd = str;
    }
};
```

And this is how my new OnExecute event looks:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::MITMProxyExecute(TIdContext *AContext) {
    static int index;
    TIdBytes ucBuffer;
    UnicodeString usTemp1;
    UnicodeString usTemp2;
    int calculated_length;
    int bytes_remaining;

    // getting the length in Hexa
    calculated_length = ReadMessageLength(AContext);
    if (!AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBufferIsEmpty()) {

        // reads data
        AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadBytes(ucBuffer, calculated_length);

        // displays string with calculated length and size of the data
        usTemp2 = UnicodeString("calculated length = ");
        usTemp2 += IntToStr(calculated_length);
        usTemp2 += " ucBuffer.Length = ";
        usTemp2 += IntToStr(ucBuffer.Length);
        TAddTextToDisplay *AddTextToDisplay = new TAddTextToDisplay(usTemp2);
        AddTextToDisplay->Synchronize();

        // converts the binary data into a a Hex String for visualization
        usTemp1 = BytesToHexString(ucBuffer);
        // adds an index to distinguish from previous entries.
        usTemp2 = IntToStr(index);
        usTemp2 += UnicodeString(": ");
        usTemp2 += usTemp1;
        AddTextToDisplay->setTextToAdd(usTemp2);
        AddTextToDisplay->Synchronize();
        delete AddTextToDisplay;
        index++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your `OnExecute` event handler runs in a worker thread, so you **must** synchronize with the main UI thread when calling `Display->Lines->Add()`, otherwise bad things can happen

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. That seems to be the problem as the application cannot exit, it freezes when I try to close it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added a new class and modified the OnExecute event (see update at the bottom) but still, the problem persists. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not be reading from the `IOHandler` directly at all. You are getting your communication out of sync.  `TIdMappedPortTCP` internally reads from the client before firing the `OnExecute` event, and reads from the target server before firing the `OnOutboundData` event.  In both cases, the bytes received are made available in the `TIdMappedPortContext::NetData` property, which you are not processing at all.

You need to do all of your parsing using just the `NetData` only, iterating through its bytes looking for complete messages, and saving incomplete messages for future events to finish.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <IdGlobal.hpp>
#include <IdBuffer.hpp>

bool ReadMessageData(TIdBuffer *Buffer, int &Offset, TIdBytes &Data)
{
    // has enough bytes?
    if ((Offset + 2) > Buffer->Size)
        return false;

    // read the length of the message from the first two bytes
    UInt16 binLength = Buffer->ExtractToUInt16(Offset);

    // converting from hex binary to hex string
    String bcdLength = String().sprintf(_D("%04hx"), binLength);

    // converting from hex string to int
    int calculated_length = bcdLength.ToInt() - 2;

    // has enough bytes?
    if ((Offset + 2 + calculated_length) > Buffer->Size)
        return false;

    // reads data
    Data.Length = calculated_length;
    Buffer->ExtractToBytes(Data, calculated_length, false, Offset + 2);

    Offset += (2 + calculated_length);
    return true;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MITMProxyConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    AContext->Data = new TIdBuffer;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MITMProxyDisconnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    delete static_cast<TIdBuffer*>(AContext->Data);
    AContext->Data = NULL;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MITMProxyExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    static int index = 0;

    TIdBuffer *Buffer = static_cast<TIdBuffer*>(AContext->Data);
    Buffer->Write(static_cast<TIdMappedPortContext*>(AContext)->NetData);
    Buffer->CompactHead();

    TAddTextToDisplay *AddTextToDisplay = NULL;
    TIdBytes ucBuffer;
    int offset = 0;

    while (ReadMessageData(Buffer, offset, ucBuffer))
    {
        String sTemp = String().sprintf(_D("%d: ucBuffer.Length = %d ucBuffer = %s"), index, ucBuffer.Length, ToHex(ucBuffer).c_str());

        if (AddTextToDisplay)
            AddTextToDisplay->setTextToAdd(sTemp);
        else
            AddTextToDisplay = new TAddTextToDisplay(sTemp);

        AddTextToDisplay->Synchronize();

        ++index;
    }

    delete AddTextToDisplay;

    if (offset > 0)
        Buffer->Remove(offset);
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to do your own socket I/O, then you will have to use `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPClient` directly instead of using `TIdMappedPortTCP`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's midnight here. I will work on this tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The solution is working like a charm, which means, it is responsive (one message, one answer) and is not hanging when trying to close it. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: There is a minor error, this line is needed:

UnicodeString sTemp;

But Stack Overflow says there are too many edit requests ATM so I couldn't add it.

Comment: @Beto I have fixed the error

Comment: after modifying the solution to my particular needs I find the application hanging again. But I don't think it's because of Indy but because of C++ Builder. Could you please take a look? If yes would it be better to ask a new question or update this one?

Comment: @Beto it should be posted as a new question.