# Why is AContext->Data null in the OnExecute event?

Tags: tcp, c++builder, indy

I am implementing one of the solutions described in this question:

[How to display messages in every Indy event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877043/how-to-display-messages-in-every-indy-event)

Specifically, I am implementing solution number 2:

> Don't perform a synchronous sync, perform an asynchronous sync instead (TIdNotify, TThread::Queue(), or equivalent). There is no good reason to block your server threads waiting for the main thread to perform UI status updates.

So I changed my class to inherit from TIdNotify, changed the Synchronize methods to Notify and removed the delete statements for my previous TIdSync objects (because TIdNotify does it internally)

So far so good, now I am implementing the OnExecute event with something like this:

```cpp
    String sTemp;

    TIdBuffer *Buffer = static_cast<TIdBuffer*>(AContext->Data);
    Buffer->Write(static_cast<TIdMappedPortContext*>(AContext)->NetData);
    Buffer->CompactHead();

    TTextToDisplay *TextToDisplay = new TTextToDisplay;
    CDecoder *Decoder = new CDecoder();
    TStringList *slDecodedLines = NULL;
    TIdBytes ucBuffer;
    int offset = 0;
    while (ReadMessageData(Buffer, offset, ucBuffer)) {
        sTemp = String().sprintf(_D("%s"), ToHex(ucBuffer).c_str());
        slDecodedLines = Decoder->formatInput(sTemp);
        if(slDecodedLines)
        {
            TextToDisplay->AddStringList(slDecodedLines);
            TextToDisplay->Notify();
        }
    }

    // delete TextToDisplay;
    delete Decoder;
    delete slDecodedLines;

    if (offset > 0)
        Buffer->Remove(offset);
```

I am getting an exception on line 3 because Buffer is NULL, and Buffer is NULL because AContext->Data is NULL (AContext is not NULL).

What could I be doing wrong for this to happen?

I have implemented the events:

- OnBeofreConnect
- OnDisconnect
- OnConnect

They "print" some messages, but even if I comment their internal code the error remains. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually assigning a `TIdBuffer` object to `AContext->Data` to begin with? In my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778574/65863), I showed you how to do that in the `OnConnect` event, eg: `AContext->Data = new TIdBuffer;`

Comment: BTW, you need to create a new `TIdNotify` object every time you call `Notify()`. As soon as the main thread is done processing the `Notify()` request, the `TIdNotify` object is destroyed. So, you can't reuse a `TIdNotify` object for multiple `Notify()` requests, like you could with `TIdSync.Synchronize()`

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me correct and text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the problem was solved, thank you so much. Now it is always responsive and the server can be disabled and re-enabled at will without problems.